How to determine if my refurbished iphone 12 pro has original apple screen?
Basically what the title says. By "original", it means all the 3 layers (glass, digitizer, oled) are original.
Can someone help please?

It’s not generally feasible since you would need to either have perfect trust in the chain of custody of the device or open it up and inspect the serial numbers on all the components and be able to tell from physical inspection and experience seeing hundreds of phone parts - both legitimate ones and aftermarket parts.
In newer phones (like yours), the OS does try to tell you if parts get replaced after it leaves the factory so most repairs will show in software settings as well.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102658


With iOS 15.2 and later, go to Settings > General > About to check the parts and service history of your iPhone.



For iPhone 12 models and later, you can check if the rear system, TrueDepth camera, battery, display, or rear cameras have been replaced


Consider upgrading your iOS if you don’t have new enough to get this reading.

I have iOS 17.4.1. The settings menu doesn't show any kind of warning. I feel like the bezel around the screen is not fully symmetrical (it's like 99% symmetrical). And "tap to wake" doesn't recognize "very light" touch. I went to the shop and said the screen doesn't seem original and, they replied that they can prove me the screen is original by opening the phone and showing me QR codes on the back of screen. I told them I don't want the phone to be opened. How can I know if all the 3 parts (glass, oled, digi) come from apple?

You can’t since any manufacturer of parts will put QR codes and serial numbers. There are very quality repairs, and even official parts can het installed poorly. You can’t totally be sure - if tap to wake is not reliable, have them recalibrate the screen. You should be able to tell if they are using official tools by asking to see where they open the screen and comparing to the official manual. https://support.apple.com/en-us/104913

They are not any official repair center , they are 3rd party refurbisher. What did you mean by "recalibrating the screen"?

Con el programa 3Utools se puede saber, conectas el equipo y te indica si algun periferico fue reemplazado.
http://www.3u.com
Translation:
With the 3Utools program you can know, you connect the computer and it tells you if any peripheral has been replaced

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Please note this is an English language site. In future please use a translation service before posting. We won't mind if the standard of translation isn't magical prose, as long as the point of the post is understandable and makes sense.
